# Unable to connect to SQL with VS 2012

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm unable to connect to my database that is located on my laptop. Now I'm trying to access it locally from within the same laptop.
i'm using this connection string:

`Server=localhost,49172;database=databasename;uid=user;pwd=password;`

The fields are filled with respective information. I also tried putting my latop's name instead of localhost. I tried different port numbers with no use .
I got an error:

> cn.ServerVersion threw and exception - InvalidOpertionException.(network related eroror) The next timem the error sayingthe connectionwas successful but there was a time during the pre-login handshake.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with SQL Server 2012. I also tried installingthe mysql connector net. My database was created with phpmyadmin web interface that uses the xampp control panel.
Any help please? I'm making an aspx webpage with c# as the code behind.

I tried adding these tags `Integrated security` and removing the user and password tags with no luck

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

How you connect the MySQL server (You mention SQL but later Mysql so hence I write this answer for Mysql).

Try to open services. Check if Mysql is running or not. Check if firewall make it hard to connect to the mysql services.

Try to remove database from connectionstring (that you pasted to connect). If that works it means you didn't have access to Database.

BTW this connectionstring is totally incorrect. "Server=localhost,49172;database=databasename;uid=user;pwd=password;"

Are you sure 49172 is the port you are using. Try to define port like this way https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ to fix it.

If you didn't changed your port then by default it will be 3306.

I hope this will fix your issues.